# How to stop windows processes being created with the same id?

Tags: process, visual-studio

I am trying to compile a big project using Visual Studio 2010 express. This is one big project with like around 700 other sub-projects compiling. Now during the compilation some times the processes(could be link.exe or lib.exe or cl.exe) get "Suspended", which I then kill off to ensure that the compilation proceeds. If this process was using lets say process id 100, any subsequent process which is created with this recycled process id also ends up being suspended.

Is there any way to stop the processes from being assigned this process id so that they don't end up being "suspended"?

Comment: You could use "Process Explorer" to find out, why the processes are actually waiting. Rather than killing them, I would try to cure the reason for them to wait. It might be a shortage of resources or some bottleneck. Are you still working with Windows XP? Or would it be an option to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 Express and see if your problem goes away?

Comment: Automated BuildStudio? http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/software-release-management

Comment: @AxelKemper Hey how to figure out why the process are waiting? I use Process explorer, but could see how I could figure out what the process is waiting on.

Comment: If you doubleclick on a process in Process Explorer, you can open the list of threads of this process. Frequently, one can tell from the threads, what's going on or what is waiting. There might be a thread in a spinning wait. Process Explorer will also show you if the processes are definitely suspended or just slow. Look at the "Image" information of the slow process to find out if the commandline parameters make sense.